# Convert a specific type of sting in Date Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have to convert the below string in DateTime. I have used following code for that but it was not working.

```
DateTime created = DateTime.ParseExact("Sun Feb 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0550", "ddd mmm d yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

My string to which I have to convert in Date Time is--

```
Sun Feb 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0550
```

Comment: Do you get any error? What is currently stored in `created`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need uppercase month and `'GMT'zzz`

```
DateTime created = DateTime.ParseExact("Sun Feb 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0550"
            , "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz"
            , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would parse this as a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime` - after all, that's the data you've been given. Assuming it's *always* specified using `GMT+...` you can use a format string of `"ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz"`. In particular, note:

- `MMM` is abbreviated month name, not `mmm`
- `'GMT'` will always match the letters 'GMT'
- `zzz` is a UTC offset including minutes. It would be *formatted* with a colon, but apparently it's permissive enough without the colon being specified.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact
            ("Sun Feb 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0550",
             "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz",
             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dto); // 23/02/2014 00:00:00 +05:50
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
DateTime created = DateTime.ParseExact("Sun Feb 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0550",
  "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz",
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```